# UFT automation testing on C#

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, hp-uft

I am currently using UFT (HP product - QTP)
I need to automate test scripts against an application called Cherwell.
Cherwell is written in C# and .net
UFT addon for .net selected but there is not addon in UFT for C# (?)
All the fields are represented by click co-ordinates and this will not replay

Has anyone automated Cherwell?
Has anyone automated against C#?
Can it be done with UFT?

Comment: Can you show example code?  What does the object spy show when you point it at elements in the UI?

Comment: I'm not familiar with UFT, but I am a developer/implementer of many Cherwell environments and can tell you that nearly all of the actions available within the client can be automated via the internal 'OneStep' scripts. Is there something specific you're looking to automate within Cherwell?

Answer (score 2):

If using .Net and C#, we have two technology options:  Winforms or WPF, so try loading both addins. Now, it is expected that UFT should recognize them using specific test objects like **Swf**Button or **Wpf**Button (the prefix of the test object will depend on the technology. You can use this to determine your app's technology).

If still nothing, try adjusting "Record and Run settings" from Record menu. From "Windows Applications" tab, select the option "Record and Run test on any open Window-based application".

Answer (score 1):

HP UFT supports automating against the .NET Framework. Your C# application is of that breed. You will need to make sure that HP UFT is fully patched. You can work with HP to ensure this is the case. Simply open a support ticket and provide your SAID designating the kind of license and support you have paid for. Please refer to the support matrix provided by [Joe Colantonio](http://www.joecolantonio.com).

[HP UFT Support Matrix](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2015/08/10/hp-uft-12-5-support-matrix-with-patch-updates/)